# How do I link my image files in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to link my image file so whenever I have update for that image it will also update the image file inside my document.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by following this steps

1. Click insert tab
2. Click picture
3. Choose the picture(s) you want to put in your document
4. Notice the small dropbox (Or combobox?) near the cancel button
5. Choose insert and link

[image]